# Constructing printable representation of an object similar to __repr__ in Python

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ mostly have used Python in the past and am looking for a way to easily construct a printable representation of an object - similar in vein to Python's **repr**. Here are some snippets from my code (it's a bank of course).

```
    class Account   {
    private:
        int pin;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        char minit;
        int acc_num;
        float balance;
        float limit;
    public:
        float getBalance(void);
        string getName(void);
        void setPin(int);
        void makeDeposit(float);
        void makeWithdrawal(float);
        Account(float initialDeposit, string fname, string lname, char MI = ' ', float x = 0);
    };
Account::Account(float initialDeposit, string fname, string lname, char MI, float x)  {
    cout << "Your account is being created" << endl;
    firstName = fname;
    lastName = lname;
    minit = MI;
    balance = initialDeposit;
    limit = x;
    pin = rand()%8999+1000;
}
```

Account object constructed. I want to have a Bank object which is essentially an array of account objects.

```
    class BankSystem    {
    private:
        vector<Account> listOfAccounts;
        int Client_ID;
    public:
        BankSystem(int id);
        void addAccount(Account acc);
        Account getAccount(int j);
    };
BankSystem::BankSystem(int id)  {
    Client_ID = id;
    listOfAccounts.reserve(10);
}
```

I would like to give the `Bank` class `showAccounts` method function which displays to the user all the account objects that they have access to. I'd like to make this printable so I can display it in `cout`. In Python I'd simply just use the `__repr__` to "stringify" the account objects e.g.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Account(x=%s, y=%s)' % (self.x, self.y)
```

Wondering how I'd go about doing the same in C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to go about this is to overload the `operator<<` function for output streams with your class, for example

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:

    // make the output function a friend so it can access its private 
    // data members
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Something&);

private:
    int a{1};
    int b{2};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Something& something) {
    os << "Something(a=" << something.a << ", b=" << something.b << ")";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    auto something = Something{};
    cout << something << endl;
}
```

Comment: As an additional followup is it possible for you to do something like: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Something& something) {
    os << "Something(a=" << something.getA() << ", b=" << something.b << ")";
    return os;
}`

Where `getA()` is a method function of `class something` which returns the value of `a`?

Comment: That is definitely an option! And a lot of people will argue that that is the way it should be done I decided to go with this for 1. Simplicity and 2. it didn't matter much here is because the object is const. it conveys the fact that data members will not change.

Answer (score 1):

A good replacement for __repr__ is:

```
class MyClass{
// whatever attributes or functions you want to put in here

    // the __repr__ equivelant function
    operator std::string() const{
        // whatever you want to do to modify the output
        return "whatever you want to put in here"; // the output of the __repr__
    }
};
```

The only issue is that you have to assign it to a string first like this, then output the string:

```
MyClass myClass;
std::string str = myClass;
std::cout<<str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
void BankSystem::showAccounts(){
    for (Account a: listOfAccounts){
        a.showAccount();
    }
}

void Account::showAccount(){
    cout << //all your printing information you want using your account
            //class variables
}
```